# tinymce get html content and place it as email body using ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, tinymce, dynamics-crm

I'm using tinymce editor for sending an email.While sending actual email in mscrm activities and ember.js framework ,Email body is sent as HTML source not as actual HTML format.
E.g while receiving an email I got format as '<'strong'>test<'/strong'>'

not as 'test' in bold.Please suggest.

below is the init function i have used

RichTextArea = Ember.TextArea.extend({
    editor: null,
    _suspendValueChange: false,
    didInsertElement: function () {
        debugger;
        var id = "#" + this.get("elementId");
        var view = this;
        tinyMCE.init({
            width: "700",
            height: "400",
            plugins : "table,inlinepopups",

```
        // Style formats
        style_formats : [
                {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
                {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
                {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
                {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
                {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
                {title : 'Table styles'},
                {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
        ],

        formats : {
            alignleft : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'left'},
            aligncenter : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'center'},
            alignright : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'right'},
            alignfull : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'full'},
            bold : {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'bold'},
            italic : {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'italic'},
            underline : {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'underline', exact : true},
            strikethrough : {inline : 'del'},
            customformat : {inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#00ff00', fontSize : '20px'}, attributes : {title : 'My custom format'}}
        },
        mode: "specific_textareas",
                    editor_selector : "mceEditor",
                    theme: "advanced",
                    theme_advanced_resizing: true,
        //// Theme options
        //            theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,|,table,removeformat,code",
        //            theme_advanced_buttons2: "",
        //            theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
        //            theme_advanced_buttons4: "",
        //            theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        //            theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        //            theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        //            theme_advanced_resizing: true,
                   theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
                    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        selector: id,
        element_format : 'html',
        setup : function(ed) {
            view.set("editor", ed);
            ed.onKeyUp.add(function (ed, e) {
                view.suspendValueChange(function () {
                    view.set("value", ed.getContent());
                });
            });
        },
        valid_styles: {
            '*': 'border,font-size',
            'div': 'width,height'
        }
    });
},
suspendValueChange: function(cb) {
    this._suspendValueChange = true;
    cb();
    this._suspendValueChange = false;
},
valueChanged: function() {
    if (this._suspendValueChange) { return; }
    var content = this.get("value");
    this.get("editor").setContent(content);
}.observes("value"),
willClearRender: function() {
    this.get("editor").remove();
}
```

});

Comment: Did you try to look at a source code of a mail you recieving? You should examine headers (content-type must be text/html, not text/plain) and body (is it &lt;strong or <strong in there). Maybe problem not in ember/tinymce, but in code that actually sends an email.

Comment: Thanks Gennady ..I checked this...Actually problem was there in Email sending web service ...Its not on tinyMCE side. :)